# Software Engineering industry - In recruiters' point of view, is candidate with MAS degree less competitive than one with MS degree?

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, united-states

I have a friend who is very interested in embedded system design specifically, and he has been looking for a position in related fields since he graduated with a bachelor degree of Electrical Engineering.

However, a lot of the positions he applied to required a master of science degree at minimal, so he started applying for master degrees. The problem is, since he didn't have an above average grade in college, he only got accepted by one MAS ([Master of Advanced Study](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Advanced_Studies)) degree program.

If he uses MAS degree to apply for positions which requires a master of science degree, will the difference hurt his chance at preliminary screening?

Note: My friend is currently looking for work in United States

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a company is looking for someone with a certain level of education, a candidate that applies with anything less is going to have a harder time competing with other people who *do* have the requested education.

Now that isn't to say that getting an MAS is a bad thing. More education is always more education. Remember that education requirements are there to ensure that the candidate is capable of doing the job. The more your friend is able to demonstrate his/her capabilities, the better their chance is going to be for getting hired on.

Say someone applies at the same time as your friend, and this person meets all of the requirements including an MS degree. Your friend is then going to have to have something else going for him that this other people doesn't. A few ideas that come to mind:

- Real world experience. A portfolio is always a great substitute to formal education, showing that (s)he is capable of doing the work that they were taught.
- Additional certifications. Certifications stress and test your ability to excel in an area. Studying for and obtaining certifications relevant to the job (s)he is going for is a great way to say "I've trained extra hard for this line of work".
- Starting in a position with more lenient requirements. Getting that real-world experience will help him/her learn on-the-job and substitute the education that (s)he's already received.

Comment: Another real plus is that this gives him a chance to improve that GPA and show he has matured enough to get good grades now.

Comment: I've noticed that this question is closed due to my unclear question description. However, I'll accept this as answer and thank you for the answer.